# Drawing polygons (triangles) in DirectX/Direct2D/Direct3D

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, direct3d, direct2d

Is it possible to do something like this in Direct2D or Direct3D?

[image: Cone image]

I want to do something like this using Direct2D/Direct3D but a flat 2D shape similar to the one shown in the picture. Thanks

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to Direct2D? Do you want to draw a simple triangle, or do you want to draw this entire mesh field with a "raised" triangle?

Comment: @Pod I want to draw a simple triangle as part of the sonar scan from the ARIA robot simulator. As long it's using DirectX, I don't mind if it's a mix of D2D or D3D. So far I've only used D2D but if D3D can be mixed into it then that's fine.

Comment: @SilentFart Am I right to assume it's not a triangle but a circle sector (round outer edge) since it's a sonar scan?

Comment: @Chexxor That's right.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exact answer..but could be guide.

```
D2D1Factory*           pD2DFactory      = NULL;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pD2DRenderTarget = NULL; 
ID2D1DCRenderTarget*   pD2DDCRenderTarget=NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap*           pD2DBitmap       = NULL;

D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED,&pD2DFactory);


RECT rc = {dx,dy,dx+dw,dy+dh};
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
       D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
       D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
       0,0, D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE, D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT);

pD2DFactory->CreateDCRenderTarget(&props,&pD2DDCRenderTarget);
pD2DDCRenderTarget->BindDC(hDC,&rc);
pD2DDCRenderTarget->CreateBitmap (D2D1::SizeU(sw,sh),(void*)p_bmp,pitch,
            D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)),
            &pD2DBitmap);

pD2DDCRenderTarget->BeginDraw();    
pD2DDCRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(pD2DBitmap,
            D2D1::RectF((FLOAT)dx,(FLOAT)dy,(FLOAT)dw,(FLOAT)dh),1.0,D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR,
            D2D1::RectF((FLOAT)sx,(FLOAT)sy,(FLOAT)sw,(FLOAT)sh));  
pD2DDCRenderTarget->EndDraw();      

SafeRelease(&pD2DBitmap);
SafeRelease(&pD2DDCRenderTarget);       
SafeRelease(&pD2DFactory);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but yeah it isn't quite right